# What are the buttons that I need to press in order to kill predators?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

For some reason, Assasin's Creed 3 doesn't show me the buttons I need to press in order to kill predators when they charge at me (a really strange bug, I know), so I lose every time.

This is quite annoying, considering it's a great income and one of the Hunting Society's missions. So... what are the buttons that I need to press in order to kill predators? I know the first one is "interact", but what are the rest?

Comment: Cover yourself in mud to fool their heat detection. Be warned, mortally wounding one may cause it to activate its nuclear self-destruct sequence.

Comment: I don't believe there is a set order. Pretty sure it's random.

Comment: What system is this on? PC? XBOX? PS3?

Comment: In my experience, the first one was always the Interact button, but the second one can be any one of the three other buttons. It's random. So I guess you'd just have to push one of them randomly and hope it's the right one? Sounds like an awful bug.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the HUD SSI option turned off? According to several sources, that would cause the button prompt sequence (or QTE Quick-Time Event) to not appear. The solution would be to enable the SSI option in the HUD again!

According to [this post](http://www.gamespot.com/assassins-creed-iii/forum/hud-off-problem-64508265/), you should be fine if you leave on the "Controls" option.

Read more [here](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/723629-Wolves-Button-prompts-don-t-appear-when-SSI-turned-off-patch-please!-Forums), [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/621797-assassins-creed-iii/64662240), [here](http://www.neoseeker.com/forums/56508/t1799470-fighting-off-animals/) and [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/621796-assassins-creed-iii/64580294).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get it fixed. Once you do this is how you do it: attack a bear for insistence, it will pounce on you. When it does buttons should come up either x,a,y, or b. Whichever button comes up is the button you are supposed to press. You do that 1-5 times and you will either die, or kill the animal.